# JavaScript: multiple filters chain vs. complex condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

Very often you need to filter an array with more than one condition:

```
return results
  .filter(x => controlGroup[x] !== undefined)
  .filter(x => x.size > 10)
```

or you could do the same with a complex condition and a *single* `filter`:

```
return results
  .filter(x => controlGroup[x] !== undefined && x.size > 10)
// or
  .filter(x => 
    controlGroup[x] !== undefined // <- Prettier would place && here. What a joke. 101
    && x.size > 10
  )
```

My guess is that since the second approach doesn't iterate the array multiple times, it has better performance characteristics,

<strike>on the other hand, the first wins in readability and can be easily extended with neat git diff LOC.</strike>

- **What is better for the performance?**
- <strike>**Should I choose performance or readability?**

  *(In this case, is the performance gain (if any) worth the cognitive overhead?)*</strike>

---

In my particular case I have a function on a Node.js server that runs 3 times per request on a set of ~40 items *(after the `flat()`)*. There is already lots of iterations and some lambda functions, so I even kind of doubt that micro-optimizing the two filters would make a difference. I believe it could all be rewritten using just a single `reduce` to save 7 iterations (if I count correctly), but at *what cost*?
*PS: I am looking for a general answer, but you could answer my particular case as a bonus. Thank you.*

```
export const getProductFeatures =
  (technicalSpecifications: TechnicalSpecifications, featuresBySpecLabel: FeaturesBySpecLabel): ProductFeature[] =>
    [...technicalSpecifications
      .map(specGroup => specGroup.specifications)
      .flat()
      .filter(spec => featuresBySpecLabel[spec.label] !== undefined)
      .filter(spec => verifyFeature(spec, featuresBySpecLabel[spec.label]))
      .reduce((productFeatures, spec) => {
        productFeatures.add(featuresBySpecLabel[spec.label].featureLabel)
        return productFeatures
      }, new Set<string>())]
      .map(label => ({ label }))
```

Comment: I see you are hating this question and that there is a close vote for "**opinion-based**". Does it mean that there is **no performance** impact whatsoever? In that case, I would take NO for an answer too.

Comment: Constants are usually ignored when computing `O` notation. I.e. `O(n)` and `O(2n)` are considered equivalent. Whether it has an observable impact depends on the size of your data, the machine the code is run on, etc. However I'd argue that you can't see any difference with 40 items. But there is an easy way to find that out: Measure the execution time of your code.

Comment: Technically two filters take twice as long as one filter (worst case) but it doesn't really make any difference if it takes 20 nanoseconds instead of 10 nanoseconds. The answer to "readability or performance" is *always* readability unless you specifically have a problem with performance and the non-readable version makes a *measurable* difference. See also [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @GuyIncognito—but readability is subjective. Chaining calls to *filter* that can be achieved with `&&` is ugly. IMHO of course. ;-)

Comment: Voting to close doesn't mean the voters hate the question, just that they think it's not within the SO posting guidelines. A general response will definitely be subjective, should readability **always** trump performance? Whose version of "readability" wins? Similarly for a specific case: what defines more or less readable vs more or less performant, particularly given different implementations have different performance characteristic depending on code structure (aka "readability").

Comment: @RobG Thank you, for clarifying that. I didn't realise it was opinion based until I read the answer to my question in the other comments. The problem here is that I've got the base assumption completely wrong by not thinking about the complexity. I wouldn't ask that otherwise.

Comment: I will take the shame and keep this QA up for anyone stumbilng upon this. Since I couldn't find an answer to my question, it's still valid in my eyes and in the end, I did find an answer to my Q here in the comments after all. If you could not-close this QA, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: There is no shame here. It's a reasonable question, just that SO isn't the right place to ask it. :-)

Comment: @RobG I could easily edit the question and remove the *performance vs readability* bits to make it appear worthy this site by only asking about performance gains, but since I asked for `x` assuming `y` and overlooked a *(huge)* detail, we can assume that there will be others who just use a similar wrong google search query and end up here, getting their wake up slap right into the face :) *(as I did)*. /edit. I did it! I edited The Question. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, there is **no significant performance improvement** for the particular case of ~40 items in an array.

Technically, each additional iteration increases the time complexity n-times in worst case, so with 2 iterations *`O(2n)`*, it could take twice as long, but we are talking about time spans way down in the nano-scale, eg. `10ns` vs `20ns` in this particular case. It might become worth considering depending on the **size of the dataset**, the **machine the code is run on**, etc.

> Constants are usually ignored when computing `O` notation. I.e. `O(n)` vs `O(2n)`.
> ~ Felix Kling *(taken from comments)*

That being said, the performance can be taken out of the question, which now leaves only the **readability** factor, which is hugely **subjective and opinion based**. Such QAs are not allowed on SO. To get an answer to this, anyone wondering should probably discuss this with their team or decide by heart. Generally though, readability is more often than not valued more for an equivalent code, which the above is. However, what anyone considers *better readable* depends on personal preferences or team/company guidelines.